# Keys not getting identified while testing on Appium

Tags: flutter, appium

I need one help regarding keys not getting identified while doing automation testing on Appium. I have developed one flutter application and i have provided unique keys for every widgets.

But when I am performing automation testing on Appium ids are not getting found.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gcvn.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFEcG.png
Please provide me a solution.

I have tried adding several different keys with different names but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To select flutter widgets or UI components with their [Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) defined in flutter code you need to use the  [appium-flutter-driver](https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver) as the **appium driver** and `appium:automationName` and **appium-flutter-finder**, which is a companion finder for Appium Flutter Driver, to select widgets in the same way as we do it in flutter integration tests, like:
`byType('TextField')` or `byValueKey('counter')`

There is luckily a java implementation that can be found [here](https://github.com/ashwithpoojary98/javaflutterfinder)